# Resolve constraint conflicts when decreasing height of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have implemented a custom `UITableViewCell` that has a `UISlider` with two `UIVimageView`s to the left and right of it in the cells' `contentView`. I've set up Auto Layout constraints for these elements. The `UISlider` has top and bottom vertical spacing constraints to the `contentView` with leading and trailing set to the images. The images also have top and bottom vertical spacing constraints to the `contentView`. This works great, but I need to have the ability to 'remove' these cells at some point in time and I do so by changing the height of the `UITableViewCell` to 0. This works just fine - there are no appearance issues, even after expanding the cells again. The only issue is an auto layout issue is logged to console when I collapse the cell:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170489010 UITableViewCellContentView:0x155eadd80.bottomMargin == UISlider:0x155eac820.bottom>
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the constraints break when you set the height of the `tableViewCell` to 0 is the following: you have top and bottom offset constraints that are bigger than 0.

If the total height of the cell is 0 and these constraints are positive, it means the height of the `progressView` and `imagesViews` need to be negative to satisfy them, which is an invalid. Therefore, the constraints crash.

Another solution would be to use an align vertical center constraints for your views, with some offset so that it fits your design. In this case, the constraints would not crash anymore when the height of the cell is 0.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue I simply changed that broken constraint from an Equals relation to Less Than or Equal relation.